# How to determine data distribution in SQL Server columns using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can someone show me how to compile code in T-SQL that will allow me to view the distribution of data in columns?

For example in the sample table, there is a column called `model`. In that column, 50% of the values are Fiestas. I would like to a query that will help determine the distribution of in data in columns.

I have included some sample code to help:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable 
(
     registration varchar(50),
     make varchar(50),
     model varchar(50),
     engine_size float
)
    
INSERT INTO #tmpTable VALUES
 ('JjFw5a0','SKODA','OCTAVIA',1.8),
 ('VkfCDpZ','FORD','FIESTA',1.7),
 ('5E93ZEq','SKODA','OCTAVIA',1.3),
 ('L2PPN0m','FORD','FIESTA',1.1),
 ('9xKghxp','FORD','FIESTA',1.5),
 ('WHShdBm','FORD','FIESTA',1.4),
 ('TNRHyy7','NISSAN','QASHQAI',1.2),
 ('6RNX0XG','SKODA','OCTAVIA',1.4),
 ('tJ9bOD8','FORD','FIESTA',1.1),
 ('ablFUSC','FORD','FIESTA',1),
 ('4B7RLYL','MERCEDED_BENZ','E CLASS',1.3),
 ('tlJiwVY','FORD','FIESTA',1),
 ('Fb9lcvG','FORD','FIESTA',1.4),
 ('nW4lqBC','FORD','FIESTA',1.6),
 ('LggTmL5','HYUNDAI','I20',1),
 ('2mGgSjS','FORD','FIESTA',1.1),
 ('IDvOzcM','FORD','FIESTA',1.3),
 ('JefpXK2','FORD','FIESTA',1.5),
 ('0h1uWfZ','MERCEDED_BENZ','E CLASS',1.4),
 ('ylBoGbV','MERCEDED_BENZ','E CLASS',1.7),
 ('XzoILDK','VAUXHALL','CORSA',1.8),
 ('Xhocs1Z','FORD','FIESTA',1.5),
 ('Lh2yWGa','KIA','RIO',1.5),
 ('hM5GWA0','FORD','FIESTA',1.3),
 ('PbpxkFt','FORD','FIESTA',1.7),
 ('SDHWV2r','FORD','FIESTA',1.2),
 ('n83Je2D','FORD','FIESTA',1.8),
 ('sDN0gex','FORD','FIESTA',1.2),
 ('7EICOZY','KIA','RIO',1.5),
 ('PUuMmIH','FORD','FIESTA',1),
 ('HiBwSg2','FORD','FIESTA',1.8),
 ('1yk1vDm','KIA','RIO',1.7),
 ('cMpH72R','HYUNDAI','I20',1.1),
 ('ZgQL0gt','MERCEDED_BENZ','E CLASS',1.3),
 ('jhpamQG','KIA','RIO',1.1),
 ('pk0lU2F','VAUXHALL','CORSA',1.4),
 ('fDCUeq1','FORD','FIESTA',1.1),
 ('ono5QFC','FORD','FIESTA',1.7),
 ('VohWwGR','FORD','FIESTA',1.5),
 ('Hih8dKc','SUZUKI','SWIFT',1.2),
 ('D2RNn3h','SUZUKI','SWIFT',1.2),
 ('QaYQulE','FORD','FIESTA',1.1),
 ('xmQPxAG','FORD','FIESTA',1.8),
 ('vmTqkTO','FORD','FIESTA',1.2),
 ('lvUtVUA','MERCEDED_BENZ','E CLASS',1),
 ('SFoj00d','FORD','FIESTA',1),
 ('9S6wrWV','MERCEDED_BENZ','E CLASS',1),
 ('0SBnW0z','FORD','FIESTA',1.1),
 ('HnDHdfj','MERCEDED_BENZ','E CLASS',1),
 ('RV7q947','FORD','FIESTA',1.4),
 ('JZqCtTg','FORD','FIESTA',1.7),
 ('XVgBwgi','FORD','FIESTA',1.8),
 ('iqJDsIF','FORD','FIESTA',1.6),
 ('CMbpRFa','FORD','FIESTA',1.6),
 ('vF7K5Xg','SUZUKI','SWIFT',1.1),
 ('3j6XGDH','FORD','FIESTA',1.5),
 ('ommqugM','FORD','FIESTA',1.1),
 ('LMQkPnw','NISSAN','QASHQAI',1.4),
 ('1dKgcdd','FORD','FIESTA',1.5),
 ('hC8BxiP','MERCEDED_BENZ','E CLASS',1.1),
 ('wLTWol7','FORD','FIESTA',1.6),
 ('TY8ChYN','FORD','FIESTA',1.6),
 ('Gw1CpI8','FORD','FIESTA',1.4),
 ('L4OPAJq','FORD','FIESTA',1.1),
 ('6TyYpfi','NISSAN','QASHQAI',1.6),
 ('ozoOcGL','FORD','FIESTA',1.4),
 ('6IME19U','FORD','FIESTA',1.4),
 ('BxpmJO5','FORD','FIESTA',1.4),
 ('0zc2n5A','FORD','FIESTA',1.3),
 ('FqbBZE2','FIAT','500',1.7),
 ('2EkTOTz','FORD','FIESTA',1.4),
 ('fNBvIvg','MERCEDED_BENZ','E CLASS',1.2),
 ('u5j4R4S','KIA','RIO',1.4),
 ('zpWaUZo','FORD','FIESTA',1.1),
 ('FQPVQYc','NISSAN','QASHQAI',1.7),
 ('8RBQADq','KIA','RIO',1.7),
 ('TOz2bcT','HYUNDAI','I20',1.7),
 ('jebhCex','FORD','FIESTA',1.3),
 ('cdHA1gL','FORD','FIESTA',1.2),
 ('FoaN4AT','FORD','FIESTA',1.7),
 ('atGn288','FORD','FIESTA',1.5),
 ('es8VNdW','FIAT','500',1.3),
 ('hDWoMXa','KIA','RIO',1.4),
 ('Q9C6Br1','KIA','RIO',1.5),
 ('mFSy4aF','FORD','FIESTA',1.6),
 ('bbbKnrM','SKODA','OCTAVIA',1.5),
 ('qY7lz6I','FORD','FIESTA',1),
 ('8Ch2OeU','VAUXHALL','CORSA',1.3),
 ('dcWsjJv','VAUXHALL','CORSA',1.3),
 ('bnnoBPg','SKODA','OCTAVIA',1.8),
 ('mvDyYkK','FORD','FIESTA',1.4),
 ('KpWDYap','FORD','FIESTA',1.3),
 ('7EK9K4z','FORD','FIESTA',1.3),
 ('ZPLHtlP','FORD','FIESTA',1.6),
 ('4EpYeSB','FORD','FIESTA',1.6),
 ('O1eZ20M','FORD','FIESTA',1),
 ('WfVntKk','FORD','FIESTA',1.7),
 ('6VlkBdi','FORD','FIESTA',1.1),
 ('hFQfKjk','KIA','RIO',1.4),
 ('3Y4njNP','KIA','RIO',1),
 ('3UuNqG0','FORD','FIESTA',1.7),
 ('qpvMYAu','FORD','FIESTA',1.1),
 ('NCYJUqx','FORD','FIESTA',1.3),
 ('M0AvWzg','FORD','FIESTA',1.6),
 ('XbVmtFf','FORD','FIESTA',1.3),
 ('l8qZy0H','SKODA','OCTAVIA',1.3),
 ('EDUbxaU','MERCEDED_BENZ','E CLASS',1.6),
 ('nWLd82o','FORD','FIESTA',1.7),
 ('4AkoyWx','FORD','FIESTA',1),
 ('nOoO25v','FORD','FIESTA',1.3),
 ('VAm5aV8','NISSAN','QASHQAI',1.4),
 ('zbd3cie','FORD','FIESTA',1.5),
 ('hyAN71W','NISSAN','QASHQAI',1),
 ('FxACHDf','FIAT','500',1.7),
 ('wOZdaeV','FORD','FIESTA',1.6),
 ('gfxZl99','VAUXHALL','CORSA',1.1),
 ('06HhwEJ','SKODA','OCTAVIA',1.7),
 ('PCTgYiG','KIA','RIO',1.7),
 ('U54WXZQ','KIA','RIO',1.6),
 ('FHgrRiF','FORD','FIESTA',1.6),
 ('R3jP73p','SKODA','OCTAVIA',1.5),
 ('etVPKX9','SUZUKI','SWIFT',1.1),
 ('BE3yReB','FORD','FIESTA',1.7),
 ('zXmX878','FORD','FIESTA',1.6),
 ('wdM3P2m','FORD','FIESTA',1.7),
 ('tb727BM','FORD','FIESTA',1.1)
    
 SELECT * FROM #tmpTable
```

Comment: Please show the expected result and also your attempt query

Comment: @Squirrel, my attempted result was as follows:

`SELECT
  table1.registration
 ,table1.make
 ,table1.model
 ,table1.engine_size
 ,NTILE(20) OVER (ORDER BY table1.registration) AS partbyme
FROM dbo.table1
ORDER BY partbyme DESC`

Comment: Please update your question with the additional information

Comment: @Squirrel, I just added my attempted query

Comment: Please also show the expected result

Comment: I don't know how to show the expected result. But basically I would like a field called something like Distribution and in that field it would show % of say Fiestas in the that field. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a *Windowed Aggregate* to get the overall count:

```
SELECT make
     , model
     , count(*) as cnt        -- count per Model
     , cast(count(*) * 100.0  -- compared to all counts
            / sum(count(*))
              over () as dec(5,2)) as distribution
FROM #tmptable
group by make
     , model
order by distribution desc;
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=30587008379cd9e292707abe987cb85f)

If you want the percentage of the Model for each Make you need to add PARTITION BY:

```
SELECT make
     , model
     , count(*) as cnt        -- count per Model
     , cast(count(*) * 100.0
            / sum(count(*))   -- compared to all counts per Make
              over (partition by Make) as dec(5,2)) as distribution
FROM #tmptable
group by make
     , model
order by make, distribution desc;
```

Comment: So, this is what I've did:

```SELECT
  table1.registration
 ,table1.make
 ,table1.model
 ,table1.engine_size
 ,NTILE(20) OVER (ORDER BY table1.registration) AS partbyme
FROM dbo.table1
ORDER BY partbyme DESC``

I would like a field that says something like 'Distribution' and in that field it would show % of say Fiestas in field Model. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to make the code look good. I tried enclosing the code in `` but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: NTILE creates equally sized buckets, this is not what you want according to your explanation. Check my fiddle

Comment: fiddle, you're a genius that is exactly what I wanted. 
I just did the NTILE as an illustration. But you have completely captured everything I wanted. Brilliant mate.

Comment: Added `Model` to the fiddle

Comment: oh wait. If you add Model, then what does the percentage refer to? Model, or Make?

Comment: It refers to each row in your output, i.e. to the combination of Make/Model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the ratio of the count of Ford Fiestas and the total count.

```
SELECT 100.0
       * count(CASE
                WHEN make = 'FORD'
                     AND model = 'FIESTA' THEN
                  1
              END)
       / count(*)
       FROM #tmptable;
```

---

Edit:

If you want the figures for all car models you can simply aggregate and group to get the count for each car model and divide that by the total count which you can get via a subquery.

```
SELECT make,
       model,
       100.0
       * count(*)
       / (SELECT count(*)
                 FROM #tmptable)
       FROM #tmptable
       GROUP BY make,
                model;
```

Comment: Hi Stick, thanks for reaching out. The solution your provided doesn't provide the distribution of data for all fields. But thanks

Comment: Please note, I was just using the value Fiesta as an example, but I would like to be able to determine the distribution of data for all fields

Comment: @Carltonp: That's why it would tremendously help, if always include the actual expected result in your questions. Anyway, see the edit. Is this what you want?